# Should I use extend or just add classes into the HTML?

Tags: css, architecture, sass

For example I have a navigation module.

**Method 1** is adding two classes into the HTML for the desired effect. One class is for the **base** and another for the **modification**.

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="nav nav-1">
  <li><a href="" class="" title="">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="" class="" title="">Promotions</a></li>
  <li><a href="" class="" title="">Products</a></li>
  <li><a href="" class="" title="">About Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

**SCSS:**

```
//BASE
.nav {      
    font-size: 0;    
    li {
        display: inline-block;
    }    
    a {
        font-size: 16px;
        display: block;
    }
}

//MODIFICATION
.nav-1 {        
    a {
        padding: 10px;
        background: #EEE;   
    }
}
```

**Method 2** is adding just one class into the HTML for the desired effect. The **base** is made into a placeholder and added using `@extend`.

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="nav-1">
  <li><a href="" class="" title="">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="" class="" title="">Promotions</a></li>
  <li><a href="" class="" title="">Products</a></li>
  <li><a href="" class="" title="">About Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

**SCSS:**

```
//BASE
%nav {      
    font-size: 0;    
    li {
        display: inline-block;
    }    
    a {
        font-size: 16px;
        display: block;
    }
}

//MODIFICATION
.nav-1 { 

    @extend %nav;  

    a {
        padding: 10px;
        background: #EEE;   
    }
}
```

**THE PROBLEM:**

While I find that using the extend technique removes the need for adding several classes to the HTML, I feel that it bloats the CSS. If I have `.nav-2`, `.nav-3`, ETC, the generated CSS would be like so:

```
.nav-1, .nav-2, .nav-3 {
  font-size: 0;
}

.nav-1 li, .nav-2 li, .nav-3 li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav-1 a, .nav-2 a, .nav-3 a {
  font-size: 16px;
  display: block;
}
```

Is this a good practice? Or should I just keep **Method 1**?

Comment: Not sure how to revise the question so that it's appropriate for SO. I think, it's a legitimate question about proper CSS architecture and the answer I am looking for should be more concrete (based on CSS performance and best practices) rather than opinion-based. I think one should be more correct than the other.

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not be a better practice, I'm relatively new to mixins but I've read they are usually a better choice when it comes to the compiled CSS. I don't have much time so I can't test this but it seems like it should work and will hopefully be a better option for you.

You could have for example:

```
@mixin my-nav($padding, $background) {
   padding:$padding;
   background:$background;
}
```

Then every time you need to call it:

```
.nav1 {
    @include my-nav(10px, #eee);
}

.nav2 {
    @include my-nav(20px, #333);
}
```

Hopefully this compiles better than extend and it's useful :)

If this doesn't help, reading this article should - http://www.sitepoint.com/sass-mixin-placeholder/

Comment: I think with mixins though, I may run into the problem of duplicate CSS properties instead of selectors.